# how to map array of array of string(Array[Array[String]]) into array of array of double(Array[Array[Double]])?

Tags: arrays, string, scala, list, double

I have a problem, assume I have an array of `String`s

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), Array(0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
```

and I want to convert it into `Array[Array[Double]]`. I have tried using `map` and to Double

```
 x(0).map(x => x.toDouble)
```

but how can I change the rest of the array entry? can someone help me how to change the whole array entry into a double? is this achievable with a loop or maybe `map`?

Comment: Your array of array of strings is actually an array of arrays of doubles already...

Answer (score 4):

Simply apply nested `map`s along with `Try` to handle non-numeric elements, as shown below:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val arr = Array(Array("0.1", "0.2", "0.3"), Array("0.4", "0.5", "xyz"))

arr.map( _.map{ s =>
  Try(s.toDouble) match {
    case Success(d) => d
    case Failure(_) => Double.MinValue  // Or any preferred default value
  }
} )
// res1: Array[Array[Double]] =
//   Array(Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), Array(0.4, 0.5, -1.7976931348623157E308))
```